# Constraint on existing table - unique combination of values only when another column is null

Tags: sql-server, constraint

I have a pre-existing table structured similarly to this:

```
[Username]   [Gateway]   [Code]   [ActiveTo]   [OrgId]  
=======================================================
user1        gateway      50        Null        100
user1        gateway      50        Null        101
user2        gateway2     51        Null        102
user3        gateway3     52       12/08/17     103
```

This table already has duplicate combinations of `[Username]`, `[Gateway]`, and `[Code]`.

I want to add a constraint such that any new users added have a unique combination of `[Username]`, `[Gateway]`, and `[Code]` but that ignores *two pre-existing duplicates* such as the two `user1` entries above (not ignoring new entries that match pre-existing ones).

I only want this to be applied when the duplicate's `[ActiveTo]` value is null (new entries have `ActiveTo` as null by default). So:

- Applying the constraint to the table above would ignore the two `user1` duplicates.
- Adding a row `[user2], [gateway2], [52], [Null]` would be fine.
- Adding a row `[user2], [gateway2], [51], [Null]` would then throw an error.
- Then adding a row `[user3], [gateway3], [52], [Null]` would be fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: If "old" users can belong to several organizations you might consider creating a new table `CREATE TABLE ADDITIONAL_USER_ORGANISATIONS (Username ..., OrgId ..., primary key ( Username, OrgId ));` and move violating rows there.

Answer (score 2):

Blatantly copied from A-K's answer in the similar question ([Can I add a unique constraint that ignores existing violations?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43823/can-i-add-a-unique-constraint-that-ignores-existing-violations/43833#43833)) and adjusted for this one.

It assumes there is an `ID` column with a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Example
ADD IgnoreThisDuplicate integer NULL;
GO
UPDATE E
SET IgnoreThisDuplicate = ID
FROM dbo.Example AS E
WHERE EXISTS 
( 
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Example AS P1
    WHERE 
        P1.Username = E.Username
        AND P1.Gateway = E.Gateway
        AND P1.Code = E.Code
        AND P1.ActiveTo IS NULL 
        AND E.ActiveTo IS NULL
        AND P1.ID < E.ID
);
GO
-- This constraint is not trusted
ALTER TABLE dbo.Example 
WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Example_NoNewDuplicates 
    CHECK (IgnoreThisDuplicate IS NULL);
GO
-- Applying the constraint to the table above would ignore the two user1 duplicates.
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.Example;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX 
    UNQ_Example_UniqueNewUsernameGatewayCode 
ON dbo.Example
    (Username, Gateway, Code, IgnoreThisDuplicate)
WHERE 
    ActiveTo IS NULL;
```

Test it out: [`db<>fiddle` demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=433d18434cf51e6e16c96c294af947a4)